# Not able to to register namespace 'Microsoft.AlertsManagement' through ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template, azure-cli

I am trying to build my infrastructure and my infrastructure through ARM templates. But getting the following error.

```
{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
    "code": "MissingSubscriptionRegistration",
    "message": "The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.AlertsManagement'. See https://aka.ms/rps-not-found for how to register subscriptions.",
    "details": [
        {
            "code": "MissingSubscriptionRegistration",
            "target": "Microsoft.AlertsManagement",
            "message": "The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.AlertsManagement'. See https://aka.ms/rps-not-found for how to register subscriptions."
        }
    ]
}
```

}

When I checked further it looks like my subscription is not registered to the resource provider  'Microsoft.AlertsManagement' (See picture below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTxDD.jpg

I know how I can fix this by going through the Azure portal and registering my Azure Subscription. But I am not able to do the same through ARM templates. Anyone has seen a similar issue and how can I fix it.

I believe it has something to do with the API version of

```
    "applicationInsightsApiVersion": "2015-05-01",
```

I am not quite sure what could be the issue, I tried changing the version of the API but no help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering a resource provider is done at the subscription level.
Looking at the supported resources to deploy ARM template at the subscription level, it is not possibe:

[Subscription deployments with ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-subscription?tabs=azure-cli#supported-resources)

Your best option would be to use Az CLI or Az Powershell as describe here:

[Resolve errors for resource provider registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-register-resource-provider)

Az Powershell:

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.AlertsManagement
```

Az CLI:

```
az provider register --namespace Microsoft.AlertsManagement
```